# fail init ALSA for 24bit file with SND_PCM_FORMAT_S24_3LE format

Tags: c, audio, alsa, 24-bit

I am trying to playback 24bit wav file with 3-bytes sample allignment using ALSA (`libasound.so.2`). And ALSA fails on setting buffer size with `Invalid argument` error (and ALSA do not pass anything to drivers)

Here is `wav` file header content:

```
chunkId:       46464952                                         
chunkSize:     221417340                                        
format:        "WAVE"                                           
subchunk1Id:   "fmt "                                           
subchunk1Size: 40                                               
audioFormat:   fffe                                             
numChannels:   2                                                
sampleRate:    88200                                            
byteRate:      529200                                           
blockAlign:    6                                                
bitsPerSample: 24                                               
cbSize         16                                               
wValidBitsPerSample 18                                          
dwChannelMask  0                                                
SubFormat                                                       
subchunk2Id:   "data"                                           
subchunk2Size: 221417280
```

Unfortunately cannot provide proper test program source as it is part of cross-platform program and wount build separately. The shorten example might looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                          
#include <stdint.h>                                                         
#include <sys/ioctl.h>                                                      
#include <sys/types.h>                                                      
#include <sys/stat.h>                                                       
#include <unistd.h>                                                         
#include <fcntl.h>                                                          
#include <errno.h>                                                          
#include <string.h>                                                         
#include <semaphore.h>                                                      
#include "asoundlib.h"                                                      

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{                               
   int err = -1;                           /**< ALSA & clib function return code */
   snd_pcm_t *p_handle = NULL;             /**< pointer to active pcm object */    
   static const char *const p_device = "default";   /**< const pointer to const device id string */
   unsigned int sampleRate = 0;                                                                    
   unsigned int rbuffertime = 0;    /**< real buffer time as granted by ALSA */                    

   err = snd_pcm_open(&p_handle, p_device, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
   if (0 > err)                                                        
   {                                                                   
      printf("Playback open error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));          
      return err;                                                      
   }                                                                   

   /* Get full range of possible hw params */
   err =  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(p_handle, p_hwparams);
   if (0 > err)                                       
   {                                                  
      printf("Error fetching hw param ranges: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
      return err;                                                       
   }                                                                    

   // Specify a specific config out of configuration space and set it
   err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_resample(p_handle, p_hwparams, 1);
   if (0 > err)
   {
      printf("Unable to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_resample for playback: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
      return err;
   }

   err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(p_handle, p_hwparams, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
   if (0 > err)
   {
      printf("Unable to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access for playback: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
      return err;
   }

   err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(p_handle, p_hwparams, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S24_3LE);
   if (0 > err)
   {
      printf("Unable to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format for playback: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
      return err;
   }

   err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(p_handle, p_hwparams, 2);
   if (0 > err)
   {
      printf("Unable to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels for playback: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
      return err;
   }

   sampleRate = 88200;
   err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(p_handle, p_hwparams, &sampleRate, 0);
   if (0 > err)
   {
      printf("Unable to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate for playback: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
      return err;
   }

   rbuffertime = 500000;
   err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_time_near(p_handle, p_hwparams, &rbuffertime, 0);
   if (0 > err)
   {
      printf("Unable to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_time_near for playback: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
   }

   return err;
}
```

ALSA fails on `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_time_near()` call with error

```
ALSA ERROR hw_params: set_near (BUFFER_TIME)
           value = 500000 : Invalid argument
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S24_3LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 24
FRAME_BITS: 48
CHANNELS: 2
RATE: 88200
PERIOD_TIME: (476 247688)
PERIOD_SIZE: (42 21846)
PERIOD_BYTES: [256 131072]
PERIODS: [2 1024]
BUFFER_TIME: (495351 495352)
BUFFER_SIZE: 43690
BUFFER_BYTES: [262144 262140]
TICK_TIME: ALL
```

(ALSA even not attempts to pass any data to drivers, just fails on set buffer)
That program works well for 16 bit audio.

I have tried different values of buffer (0.001 .. 1 second) however none of them works. Suppose I have missed any part of ALSA config required for 24 bit with 3LE, of maybe some check of previous init steps results?

Unfortunately I cannot find any example of ALSA usage for 24 bits, I would appreciate if You advice any link to example/recommendation/documentation.

EDITED

The result of `aplay` for this file is:

```
aplay -v /export/target/24bit_88.2kHz.wav
Playing WAVE '/export/target/24bit_88.2kHz.wav' : Signed 24 bit Little Endian in 3bytes, Rate 88200 Hz, Stereo
aplay: set_params:979: Sample format non available
```

Comment: What type is your `default` device? (try "`aplay -v something.wav`") PulseAudio or dmix or plug? Does it work if you try `dmix` or `plug`?

Comment: will try `dmix` and `plug`

Comment: when try with `dmix` or with `plug`, the `snd_pcm_open()` fails

Comment: Did you redefine the `default` device? That "Sample format non available" error should never happen with any of the predefined default devices.